# ubuntu 16.04 `unable to mount location`

Tags: 16.04, mount, data-recovery

I've recently installed `ubuntu 16.04`. Before installation, I've made a backup of my data (previous system was `ubuntu 14.04`). After installation I wanted to copy back my files, but I'm unable to access it. The disc doesn't appears in the files (on the left bar) under `unity`. Under `mate` I can see it, but if I try to open it, there is message `unable to mount location`.

`sudo fdisk -l` output is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298,1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x924cef05

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 617050111 617048064 294,2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       617052158 625141759   8089602   3,9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       617052160 625141759   8089600   3,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 298,1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000e1e9b

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 625141759 625139712 298,1G 83 Linux
maria@maria-Vostro-3360:/media$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media/external
```

I've created mounting point in `/media` named `external`

I've run `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/external`

The output is:

```
 mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
        missing codepage or helper program, or other error

      In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
      dmesg | tail or so.
```

I've tried `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /media/external`

Output:

```
mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist
maria@maria-Vostro-3360:/media$
```

Is there other way I should try to access the data?

UPDATE

I was trying to see the disc in GParted. This shows `unknown file system` and under the details there is following:

[image: Gparted]

Does it mean that my disc suddenly got broken?

UPDATE 3

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 320 GB / 298 GiB - CHS 38913 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 D Linux                    0  32 33 38913  70  5  625139712
 D Linux                 1215 170 44 38913  70  5  605612032
 D Linux                 1490 100 19 38913  70  5  601198592
 D Linux                19611 118 28 25015 239 56   86822912
```

UPDATE

Since it seems that the problem is not mounting but damaged filesystem, I've asked new question regarding data recovery: [Data recovery - damaged filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841976/data-recovery-damaged-filesystem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

## Problem #1

On your /dev/sda hard disk, partition sda2/sda5 is not properly aligned. This is a relatively easy fix, because it's your swap partition.

```
1. In gparted, you can select sda5 and issue a swapoff command
2. then delete sda5, then delete sda2
3. then recreate a fresh primary (not extended) swap partition, select the new partition, and issue a swapon command.
4. in terminal, type `sudo blkid` and note the UUID of the new swap partition.
5. still in terminal, edit your `/etc/fstab` with `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab` and find the line that contains the word "swap", and change the UUID to the new UUID. Save the file and quit gedit.
6. reboot the system, and in terminal, issue a `swapon` command to confirm that your new swap partition is working properly.
```

## Problem #2

You need to recover your sdb1 partition, by changing it from unknown to EXT4. It's best to use testdisk.

```
1. in terminal, type `sudo apt-get update`
2. in terminal, type `sudo apt-get install testdisk`
3. in terminal, type `sudo testdisk`
```

You can learn more about the testdisk partition recovery by visiting http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step.

Comment: I've tried your solution. I've installed testdisk and run it. Durring the deep search it stopped on 58%, finding an error. `Analyse cylinder 22785/38912: 58%
Read error at 22784/254/63 (lba=366041024)`. Since some time nothing happens.

Comment: Maria, did you already fix problem #1 using my guide? Problem #2 sounds like it's possibly a bad hard disk. Did you only have the one partition on it? Do you remember? Was it NTFS or EXT4 formatted? If you don't do a deep search, was it able to locate your existing partition and give you a chance to change it to NTFS or EXT4? If you can flip it, then mount the drive and backup whatever data you can. Let me know. Cheers, Al

Comment: I've run testdisk. I'm not sure about the choices I should do (partition type for exemple). The disk was formatted to ext4 if I remember well, I didn't make the partitions, I don't know if it should be one partition or not partitioned. The result of deep search is in UPDATE 3. Every of the partition listed seems damaged - choosing one of them and `p` - each time the result was `empty, file system might be damaged`...

Comment: I'm sorry, by mistake I've added the update to your answer instead of my question... I'm not able to remove it (or I don't know how).

Comment: p.s. First problem is solved :)

Comment: Maria, I looked at your update 3, and it's very confusing to me. The first 3 partitions all end at the same spot. Hum.  I also admit that my expertise runs out on this subject. You may just have to reinitialize the disk and start over. Cheers, Al

Comment: It means you think I've lost my data saved on the disk?

Comment: I don't have a lot of testdisk experience yet. Maybe somebody else will chime in here. You could try setting any one of the first 3 partitions as EXT4, and assume that the other 2 are false, and if it gives you immediate feedback, then great, but once you write out a new partition table, any chance to recover later using testdisk will probably be gone. I just don't know. If you have the data backed up, then it's a no-brainer, wipe the disk and restore from backups. Please do let me know how you make out. Cheers, Al

Comment: this was the backup... I've put my data on the external disk before system reistallation. When I wanted to copy it back on the computer, I couldn't... That's why it's a bit weird for me - day before the disk was fine... I mean I've managed to copy all the data on it.

Comment: You might post another question with "Need help with testdisk" and put the results of your updates 1- 3 in there, and see if somebody with more testdisk experience can help. Cheers, Al

Comment: I've asked new question: "http://askubuntu.com/questions/841976/data-recovery-damaged-filesystem". Thanks a lot for your help :)