# Data recovery - damaged filesystem

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, fsck, testdisk

I've recently installed new distribution (ubuntu 16.04, before it was ubuntu 14.04). Before installation I've copied my data on external hdd. When I was trying to copy it back, I was not able to access it. It seems that the file system (ext4) is damaged. I was able to see it with `fdisk -l commnad` but not to mount it. I've created mounting point in `/media` named `external`

I've run `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/external`

The output is:

```
 mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
        missing codepage or helper program, or other error

      In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
      dmesg | tail or so.
```

I've tried `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /media/external`

Output:

```
mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist
maria@maria-Vostro-3360:/media$
```

I was also trying to boot the computer on live ubuntu 14.04, the system which was installed when I was copying the data on the external disc, but it didn't help.

Gparted shows `unknown file system` and under the details there is following:

[image: Gparted]

I've run `testdisk`. I'm not sure if I've done it correctly (for exemple I don't know if I should choose `no partitionned` or there was one partition on my disc. I've choose the default options, i.e. partitioned, type - Linux. The result of deep search was"

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 320 GB / 298 GiB - CHS 38913 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 D Linux                    0  32 33 38913  70  5  625139712
 D Linux                 1215 170 44 38913  70  5  605612032
 D Linux                 1490 100 19 38913  70  5  601198592
 D Linux                19611 118 28 25015 239 56   86822912
```

Since it seems the filesystem is damaged I wanted to run `fsck`. I've run  `sudo fsck -r /dev/sdb1` and I got this:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8).
Clear<y>?
```

Since I don't understand really what I am doing, I typed `no`, I don't want to mess it up more and loose my data defenitly. The output was:

```
fsck.ext2: Illegal inode number while checking ext3 journal for /dev/sdb1

/dev/sdb1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

/dev/sdb1: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

/dev/sdb1: status 12, rss 3040, real 816.797699, user 0.004000, sys 0.000000
```

UPDATE: In `testdisk` I've tried to check the `non partitioned media`. Than `Advanced - filesystem utiles` shows primary partition with unknown filesystem. I've tried to change it to `ext4` and than entered `list`. The output was: `Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.`

UPDATE 2:
Following @heynnema's advice I've managed to recover something but I still don't know exactly what.  All the files and directories are in one directory `lost+found` with wired names (starting by # and after different numbers). Some of files has name of a file that I had in my computer but the name doesn't match with the content. To open the folder `lost+found` I have to use `sudo` and I'm not able to copy it:

```
root@maria-Vostro-3360:/media/maria/9db3c007-4387-4ea8-a61c-b12fa10049bc/lost+found/#3670019# cp -i /media/maria/9db3c007-4387-4ea8-a61c-b12fa10049bc/lost+found/#4718697/ /home/maria/Desktop/odzysk/1
cp: omitting directory '/media/maria/9db3c007-4387-4ea8-a61c-b12fa10049bc/lost+found/#4718697/'
```

The `.odt` file after opening it looks like this:[image: this] It was loading very long and finally I got the message that it contains some invalid characters. While I was trying to change the encoding, the file closed due to some error.

Comment: Please try to analyze it with [R-Linux](http://www.r-tt.com/free_linux_recovery/) and report if it gives any result.

Comment: Maria, hi, it's Al again. I hadn't suggested fsck before because I didn't think it would even run, but it looks like it might, so... **sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb1** and run it multiple times if errors still occur. Say yes to everything. Nothing to loose at this point. Cheers, Al

Comment: ps: this is an external USB disk, yes? After you backed up your files, did you properly dismount the drive before unplugging the USB cable? If forgot if we discussed this earlier. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Hello, Al :) Thanks again. Today my friend took the disk to try if he manage to do something, if not, he will return it to me in the evening. I've send him your comment. For dismouting the drive - I'm pretty sure I did, I mean I do it always. The previous system was installed on separated partition which got overfull so the system started freezing and blocking (like you can't do anything) - maybe something like that happened after I backed up the data? I don't remember for sure to be honest.

Comment: @heynnema I've managed to recover something. The details are under 2nd update. Could you please convert your comment into the reply, so I can accept it?

Comment: Did the fsck get you to this point? Did you try and open the .odt file in LibreOffice? I wish that we could have gotten together right after you discovered your system was full. I would have been able to do more for you, and maybe saved you a reinstall. I don't think that there's anything for me to take credit for (yet), as I don't know if you've really got any data left to work with. Thanks for keeping me in the loop. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema: Yes, it's where I got with fsck. I was trying to open all files with gedit. First, till I open it, I have no idea of what is inside (all files and directories in `lost+found` has the names like this: `#4718931` (or different number)). When I try to open it with libreoffice, I'm getting the message that the file doesn't exist. I've typed first sudo -i to be able to open the `lost+found`, than - still as a root - openoffice --writer /#4718931. (I've tried too without slash). I've tired also to open openoffice as superuser and that by `open` command, but than the external hdd is empty.

Comment: If you go to terminal and type `nautilus -q` that will quit the file manager. Don't panic if you see your desktop icons disappear. If you wanted to go back one step, you'd just click on the Files icon in the launcher... but we don't. Now type `gksudo nautilus` and that will bring up the file manager in privileged mode. Now you can access the files that you want. If your filenames have specials characters like / or #, you'll want to rename them to something like file1.odt, file2.xls, etc. Then, assuming that most of your files are LibreOffice, you should be able to open them.

Comment: @heynnema I'm not able to switch `nautilus` off. When I type `nautilus -q` I get this: 

`(nautilus:4560): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **:` `g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion` `'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed`
`(nautilus:4560): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **:` `g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion` `'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed`
`(nautilus:4560): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed`
`(nautilus:4560): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance`

Comment: `(nautilus:4560): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed`

Comment: Really?!? Reboot and try again. It's kind of normal to get some minor error noise on `nautilus -q`, but it should bring you back to the $ prompt, and your desktop icons should be temporarily missing.

Comment: @heynnema Hello. I was trying to open `nautilus` in privileged mode but it doesn't change antyting - the disc is empty. Sorry, if I open it normally, there is on left-side bar `320 g volume`, when I open is as a root, there is name of the volume...

Comment: Hello Maria! If you click on the name of the volume, it'll mount/open it, and then you can browse the files there. They may be in the lost+found folder. Type control-h to see hidden files. I've forgotten where we were, but if you don't immediately see the files, look in /mnt or /media. (if none of that works, although it's not recommended, use "sudo nautilus" instead of gksudo or gksu). Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema control-h was the solution :) I've managed to see lost+found folder, I've managed to copy it to my computer. But - it's in `/root` not `/home`. I've changed the ownership from root to normal user, but I'm not able to copy it... (I have the same message as previously "omitting directory X". I've changed the ownership of the lost+found directory on the external disc to copy it as a normal user and not a root. The same happens...

Comment: Place the lost+found folder on your Desktop. In terminal, type `cd ~/Desktop`, then type `sudo mv lost+found recovered`, then type `sudo chown -R maria:maria recovered` (change maria:maria to your username, if it's different). (cd puts terminal in your desktop directory, mv renames the folder, chown changes all of the files to your ownership).

Comment: ps: if you can't put the lost+found folder on your desktop, use the same instructions on the copy in /root (`cd /root` or `cd /root/Desktop`), or on the external disk. Then you can drag the folder anywhere you want.

Comment: @heynnema actually the problem is that I can't do it. I started copying before the separate folders from `lost+found` on external disk to the desktop on my computer. Since I was in root mode it copied to root's desktop. I was trying to copy it from root's desktop to /home/maria - I couldn't. I've changed the ownership of the directory in root's desktop i've copied the files and tried again to copy to my home. After I've changed the ownership of `lost+found` on external hdd - still I can't copy it. I've changed the name on external disk - sitll I can't copy.

Comment: the folder's name is in blue on green background. But the folder in root's desktop is in blue without background and still I can't copy it... P.S. I've checked with ls -l the ownership of the directories I'm trying to copy. It was root, now it's maria.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48090/discussion-between-maria-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an extended conversation in the comments and in chat... and just to close this question... here's what we did...

1. performed an fsck on the external hard disk drive
2. all the recovered files ended up in the lost+found folder
3. we changed the name and the ownership of the folder and its files
4. copied the folder from the external hard disk drive to the desktop
5. reviewed a few of the files and found the missing data

Comment: It was a lucky case then. Performing a `fsck` on a drive where you want to recover stuff is generally a **terrible** idea. All's well that ends well.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I agree, but it was a last ditch effort, after testdisk was not able to help via remote control. It was a pretty messed up file system, occurring on the cusp of having to rebuild the OS, for a different reason.